# Laravel constructor redirect is not working?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a controller with several methods and I need to add a specific authorization check. If authorization failed then redirect login page. So for this reason i have created one private function and this function call in constructor.

```php
class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('web');
        $this->isLogin();
    }

    private function isLogin()
    {
        if (!empty(Auth::user())) {
            echo "Hello";
        } else {
            echo "Fasd";
            return Redirect::to('/login');
        }
    }
}
```

If auth is not found is does not redirect to login. What i write extra code for this?

Comment: Thank you so much @Andrew edit my code.

Comment: You should batter to use middleware: [link](https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware)  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32164695/using-laravel-auth-middleware)

Comment: I don't want use middleware. Can you suggest me what i write wrong in my code can please help me @RahmanQaiser

Comment: Which laravel version u r using?

Comment: use return redirect('/login');

Comment: Laravel 5.2 @RahmanQaiser

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113803/discussion-between-dhanashri-and-rahman-qaiser).

Comment: I am using this return redirect('/login'); but not redirect to login

Comment: To check if user is logged in use `Auth::check()` or `Auth::guest()` to check if is not logged in.

Comment: Ya i check that but facing redirect issue..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing login page redirect use redirect::route into login page alias name routes.php.

```
public function isLogin()
{
    if (!empty(Auth::user())) {
        echo "Hello";
    } else {
        echo "Fasd";
        return Redirect::route('login');
    }
}
```

Comment: getting error Route [login] not defined. @sebahattin

Comment: The route method here is used to redirect to [named route](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#named-routes). So make sure to name it first. See [`Illuminate\Routing\Redirector`](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Routing/Redirector.html#method_route)

Comment: Route::get('/login', ['as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@login']);

Comment: @sebahattinçatal Thanks:)